# Take output from GetActions and send to database using eossharp

Tags: smart-contract, action, database

I am using **eos-sharp** to get data from the eos smart contract. I am trying to get actions data by using:

```
var resultaction = await eos.GetActions("dqzmember", 0, 30);
```

I need information from **resultaction** and pass it to **MongoDB**. How to access data from variable **resultaction** as it is of type

> EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.GetActionsResponse

How can I convert it into a string? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve the conversion between the Objects returned by EosSharp and MongoDb.

If you only want to convert the data to a string and store it in a MongoDB, it only depends on wich part of the data you want to store.

A possible simple (but CPU-consuming because of the string-conversions) solution probably looks like the following:

```
        var resultaction = await DefaultApi.GetActions(new GetActionsRequest()
        {
            account_name = "dqzmember",
            pos = 0,
            offset = 30
        });

        string globalActionJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.GlobalAction>(resultAction);
        // serializes the whole Response to a json

        foreach (GlobalAction action in resultaction.actions)
        {
            action.ToString()
            // only returns the full qualified name of the object 
            // ("EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.GetActionsResponse") or something similar

            string actionJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.GetActionsResponse>(action);
            // serializes each individual action to a json-String


            action.action_trace.act.data.ToString();
            // converts the action_trace only to string
        }
```

Once you have your json-strings, you could simply do

`BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(somejson);`

while using [MongoDB C# - BsonDocument Class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm)

and store the Document in your DB.

A better solution would be to write your own classes with serializers/serialization and convert the obejcts returned by EosSharp to something you can process in your C#-buisnes-logic.

Comment: Thanx! `BsonDocument.Parse(somejson);` This line helps me a lot.